# Rails Uncaught ReferenceError: $$ is not defined upgrading to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hey all looking throughout all of stackoverflow this looks like a common error i just cant wrap my head around. i am busy upgrading our site from pure JS to jquery in preparation for us moving over to Rails 3.1 now i have this javascript:

```
 :javascript
   ["Ownership", "Management", "EmploymentEquity", "SkillsDevelopment", "PreferentialProcurement", "EnterpriseDevelopment", "SocioeconomicDevelopment"].each(function(element) {
     $$('.' + element).each(function(s) {
       s.toggle();
     });
 });
```

so basically it is running trough an array of css classes and then toggling them. now when i run this with the jQuery lib i get an error that looks like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object Ownership,Management,EmploymentEquity,SkillsDevelopment,PreferentialProcurement,EnterpriseDevelopment,SocioeconomicDevelopment has no method 'each'
```

now i am just trying to test one element at a time to get the jQuery working at least this is what i have so far.

```
$("OwnershipHeader").click(function () {
$("Ownership").toggle("slow");
});
```

very simple so just when you click on the header it toggles its children. so when i enter that in the console it works just fine. until i click on the header of coarse:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $$ is not defined
```

this seems really simple and yet its breaking every time... i am relatively new to jQuery i have just worked with the Jquery UI lib before. any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Why are you using `$$` to begin with? was this code you were given? jQuery doesn't define `$$`, although prototype.js does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Object Ownership,Management,EmploymentEquity,SkillsDevelopment,PreferentialProcurement,EnterpriseDevelopment,SocioeconomicDevelopment has no method 'each'

I think you meant `forEach`. But since this doesn't work in all browsers, use jQuery's [`each` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$.each(["Ownership", "Management"], function(i, element) {...
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $$ is not defined

jQuery uses a single dollar sign (`$`)

```
$("OwnershipHeader").click(function () {
  $("Ownership").toggle("slow");
});
```

[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) are mostly like CSS selectors. So this should work:

```
$(".OwnershipHeader").click(function () {
  $(".Ownership").toggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var array = ["Ownership", "Management", "EmploymentEquity", "SkillsDevelopment", "PreferentialProcurement", "EnterpriseDevelopment", "SocioeconomicDevelopment"];

$.each(array, function(i,element) {
    $('.' + element).toggle();
});
```

It looks like it was coded previously with PrototypeJS, which provides `$$` and `[].each`.

I'm not sure if `.toggle` is the same behavior in PrototypeJS and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var col = ["Ownership", "Management", "EmploymentEquity", "SkillsDevelopment", "PreferentialProcurement", "EnterpriseDevelopment", "SocioeconomicDevelopment"];
$.each(col,function(i,e){
  $('.'+e).each(function(j,s){
    $(s).toggle();
  });
})
```

*in jquery first of all there is no variable defined as `$$` and only `$` is defined.
*secondly each function is used as i have mentioned and the first variable passed to the function that is provided to each is the `index in array` and second variable is the actual `element`
look here for [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) documentation

Comment: your function works as the page renders all the elements close up but if i try click on a element i get the same error  [[Uncaught ReferenceError: $$ is not defined]]

Comment: can you provide complete code.. specially the area where you are using $$. there is no place in my code where im using $$ symbol

Comment: probably you should provide a jsfiddle as i suspect there are more errors in the page